# New list form does not add entry to list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a list where I have created a custom NEW form for. When I use this as the default form and hit the submit button the new entry seems to submit fine but it does not appear in the list at all. If I switch back to the default form and submit it then it appears fine.
If I open the list in SPD2010 then the items in the list do not increment so I know it is not something simple like a view causing them not to appear.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: can you post your new "newform"? did you check the ULS Logs?

Comment: There is no error given so I have not checked the logs. What should I look for? How do you want the form - as a code extract?

Comment: yes a code extract and you could log in the logs for errors when trying to add an item to the list for example

Comment: I found this error in th elogs as when I submitted via the preview button in SPD2010 I did receive an error correlation: 09/12/2014 15:16:48.00  w3wp.exe (0x1B7C)                        0x41CC SharePoint Foundation          Logging Correlation Data       xmnv Medium   Name=Request (GET:https://MYURL/All%20Items%20Summary.aspx) f3c4719a-982a-4a35-a130-a019d98eb02f

Comment: is this the only error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What caused this issue was when I moved form controls around on my custom form the ID fields were being changed without me knowing. For example the ID of a field was ff17 and then once moved it changed to FormField18! This causes the field to not submit the value and if you have required fields then the whole list entry will not submit!
To fix this issue just make sure to change the ID back to its default value after moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me a while ago. Check the XSLT code in SP Designer and look for something like this:

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List"
```

And change it to:

```
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem"
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but it is already set to: ListItem